# What Android phones run Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to buy a couple of the most commonly used Android phones to test my app on. This is surprisingly hard to figure out.

The [Android Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) states that 2.3.3 is the most commonly used OS, but I can't seem to find any phones that run it... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) seems to say that only the HTC Flyer has it.

What Android phones could I get with Android 2.3.3?

Comment: my droid X from verizon has 2.3.4 Why do you need 2.3.3 exactly.  I guess I could have not updated it past 2.3.3.  To some degree later version should be backwards compatible.

Comment: @owengerig Because over 50% of all Android users use 2.3.3 exactly, as shown in the Dashboard.

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy Young (5360) uses Android 2.3.6

Comment: ICS is going to dominate the market eventually... I wouldn't invest too much money in a Gingerbread device at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All devices running Android `2.3.x` use the same public application framework (Gingerbread, API level 10) so there is no difference between the different revisions from a developer's point of view (other than bug fixes and optimizations). Any cheap Gingerbread device should be fine as long as you keep it updated.

Comment: This only holds true for the API and not hardware issues. Developmental details like screen sizes, screen densities, trackball presence, things like that are a little harder to work around. The emulator helps, but there's nothing like the peace of mind of seeing your app run properly on a physical device.

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense if the API version numbers don't reflected hardware differences between physical devices.

Comment: It makes complete sense that an API version wouldn't reflect hardware differences! It's the software version. What you say is correct: all 2.3.x have the same API of level 10. This does not invalidate the idea of buying multiple devices for the sake of hardware differences at this API level.

Comment: Ahh... yes, of course. What I was saying is it wouldn't make much sense to buy a new device solely for a specific API revision :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a little over a year old [LG-P500](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_one_p500-3516.php) (Optimus) which runs 2.3.3. I don't suppose you'll be able to find one in the market and most of the new ones have moved on to >= 3.0. I suppose, you could try your luck in the seconds market.

Comment: I had this exact phone up until 2 weeks ago. Decent, but I am very happy to have upgraded. Should be great for testing though.